# Chrome (57) stopped opening URLs

Tags: google-chrome

[EDIT: Now on version 58, and Chrome opens URLs when I tell it to. Yay! Hope it stays that way.]

Chrome does not seem to want to open URLs when told to any more (v 57).

I have, for a long time, used 'open -a  ' (via Java exec subprocess) to browse URLs in Chrome.

Tried setting Chrome as default browser and using:

```
Desktop.getDesktop().browse(uri);
```

This does not work either.

The URLs are mostly localhost URLs.

My solution seems to have to be to use Safari, which works, both ways (open -a with explicit app name; and as default browser as above).

Is it a bug, or tightened security? Any chance it'll change back?

Comment: Any solution to this?